# Checking if a bound column exists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

I have an SQL stored Procedure that, based on values in the database, may have a certain column in but not always. So when I'm binding the column as so `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ADDRESS1")%>` when the condition in the SP is met to not display this column the page results in an error. I can see why the error occurs because there is no column to pull through but is there any IF clause that can can do a check to find out if this exists before attempting to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have your SP create the column always. Then when databinding make the decision there to display or not to display.

Comment: Perfect and what I ended up doing in the end - thanks :)

Comment: Great... I often find manipulating the dataset is easier in the codebehind then creating sql scripts.